# How to build an expanding vaadin window with scrollbars as needed

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin7

I am builing an expanding Window/layout that shall expand/shrink on supplied data, possibly expanding to fill the browser window.

*Edit: The scroll bars shall be on the work-area, not the window.*

So far i have only managed to get it working vertically with a simple list of labels (see simple_list.png).

- Vertical scrollbar appear when browser window filled vertically Horizontal scrollbar always present and width of window/layout seems directed by length of panel title and window icons at top-right.

  *Edit: Scroll bars OK on Panel. No horizontal expansion.*
- It fails completeley for a GridLayout (see gridlayout.png).

  *Edit: I.E no scrollbars on work-area (Panel)*

The final layout is supposed to have a central work area and header, footer, left/right areas. The work area to expand according to data.

Barked up the wrong tree? CSSLayout? Not for Vaadin?

Any help/guidance appreciated.

A simplified test case below (Vaadin 7, subclassing Window).

```
public TestWindow() {

super.setSizeUndefined();

VerticalLayout vL = new VerticalLayout();
vL.setSizeFull();
super.setContent(vL);

//vL.addComponent(buildHeader());

Panel workArea = new Panel();
workArea.setSizeFull();
workArea.setCaption("View");
vL.addComponent(workArea);
vL.setExpandRatio(workArea, 1f);


//vL.addComponent(buildFooter());

//-----------------------------

VerticalLayout view = new VerticalLayout();
view.setSizeUndefined();
workArea.setContent(view);

for (int i=0; i < 100; i++) {
    String s = "view line "+i;
    for (int j=0; j < 10; j++) {
        s += "____________________"+j;
    }
    Label line = new Label(s);
    line.setSizeUndefined();
    view.addComponent(line);
}

//=============================
/*
VerticalLayout view = new VerticalLayout();
view.setSizeUndefined();
workArea.setContent(view);
GridLayout gl = new GridLayout();
gl.setSizeUndefined();
view.addComponent(gl);
view.setExpandRatio(gl,  1);
gl.setColumns(2);
for (int i=0; i < 100; i++) {
    Label line = new Label("view line "+i);
    line.setSizeUndefined();
    gl.addComponent(line);
}
*/
//------------------------------

center();

setModal(true);

setDraggable(true);

UI.getCurrent().addWindow(this);
```

}

[simple_list.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iUy3U.png)

[gridlayout.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NUSqw.png)

Comment: Updated the post with clarification on scrollbars and failing expansion of window. Scroll bars works as expected for work-area, i.e. panel scrollbars not window ditto.Expansion of window works vertically but not horizontally

Answer (score 1):

Vaadin documentation says:

> If a sub-window has a fixed or percentual size and its content becomes too big to fit in the content area, a scroll bar will appear for the particular direction. On the other hand, if the sub-window has undefined size in the direction, it will fit the size of the content and never get a scroll bar.

Source: https://vaadin.com/docs/v7/framework/layout/layout-sub-window.html